# Rserve arguments: --save vs --no-save vs --vanilla

Tags: rserve

I am trying to understand the difference between the Rserve arguments --save, --no-save, and --vanilla.  I don't see anything describing the effects of these in the documentation or any forums.  Does anyone know exactly what these do?

In OSX, I need to specify one of these to run Rserve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those are `R` arguments and documented in the R documentation as well as in `--help`:

```
$ R --help
[...]
  --save                Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-save             Don't save it
  --no-environ          Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file        Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file        Don't read the user R profile
  --restore             Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --no-restore-data     Don't restore previously saved objects
  --no-restore-history  Don't restore the R history file
  --no-restore          Don't restore anything
  --vanilla     Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file,
            --no-init-file and --no-environ
```